# Keep repeated element once and the entire data frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove rows based on the repeated element in first column but want to keep the second column as well. Any of the the values associated with repeated element in the second column I can use.

Input:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), col2 = 1:6)
```

Expected Output:

```
col1 col2
a    1
b    4
```

or,

```
col1 col2
    a    2
    b    5
```

etc.

So far tried with below command but does not keep entire dataframe:

```
df[(duplicated(df$col1)),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `col1` and then include only those groups which occur more than once and get the first row by group with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   filter(n() > 1) %>%
   slice(1)

#   col1  col2
#  <fctr> <int>
#1   a     1
#2   b     4
```

To get second row from every group we can just

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  slice(2)

#    col1  col2
#    <fctr> <int>
#1      a     2
#2      b     5
```

---

We can also use the `row_number` function in `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

the following should do what you want:

```
> df = data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), col2 = 1:6)
> t <- table(df[,1])
> df[match(names(t[t>1]),df[,1]),]
  col1 col2
1    a    1
4    b    4
```

Short explanation: `table(...)`counts the number of times each element apears in the first column. `names(t[t>1])` selects only those that appear at least two times and `match(...)` gives the (first) index of said elements. Finally the rows corresponding to these indices are selected.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, I do not want the 6th row as well. See my expected output.

Comment: So you only want those that are repeated two or more times?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'col1', `if` the number of rows are greater than 1, get the first row

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N>1) head(.SD, 1) , col1]
#   col1 col2
#1:    a    1
#2:    b    4
```

If we need the second value

```
setDT(df)[, if(.N>1) .SD[2] , col1]
#   col1 col2
#1:    a    2
#2:    b    5
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   filter(n()>1 & row_number()==1)
#   col1  col2
#  <fctr> <int>
#1      a     1
#2      b     4
```